# Parse Server how to get AuthenticationCallback after logInWithInBackground?

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-server, account-kit

how it possible to get callback after calling logInWithInBackground?
currently I'm using below code for login but don't know how to get it success result.

```
Task<ParseUser> parseUserTask = ParseUser.logInWithInBackground("facebookaccountkit", authData);
```

I want to send user to another activity after successful login.

api links:

https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html#logInWithInBackground-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-

https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/AuthenticationCallback.html

Comment: the solution is to use Bolt Task because  loginWithInBackground return Bolt Task

Comment: https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android

Answer (score 1):

You can use a continuation:

```
parseUserTask.continueWith(new Continuation<ParseUser, Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void then(bolts.Task<ParseUser> task) {

                if(task.isCancelled()){
                    showError();
                    return null;
                }
                if (task.isFaulted()){
                    showError();
                    return null;
                }

                final ParseUser user = task.getResult();
                //do something with the user
                return null;
            }
        });
```

this is taken from [Google OAuth Configuration](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/1850)